# How to get total length of all items in object with arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get the total of all items in object with array. for example

```
const obj = {
  one: [1, 4],
  two: [4, 6]
}
```

I should get total of 4.

I tried

```js
const obj = {
  one: [1, 4],
  two: [4, 6]
}

let total = 0;
const objKeys = Object.keys(obj);

for (let index = 0; index < objKeys.length; index++) {
  total += obj[objKeys[index]].length
}

console.log(total);
```

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could grab the [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) of your object, which would be an array of arrays of the following shape:

```js
[[1, 4], [4, 6]]
```

and then flatten this array with [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) which gives:

```js
[1, 4, 4, 6];
```

And then grab the `.length` of that array.

See example below:

```js
const obj = {one: [1, 4],two: [4, 6]}; 

const res = Object.values(obj).flat().length;
console.log(res);
```

Note, that if your goal is for efficiency, you can use a standard [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to loop the keys of your object, and then add to a `total` like as shown below. This also avoids the overhead of creating additional arrays to store the keys/values:

```js
const obj = {one: [1, 4], two: [4, 6]};
let total = 0;
for(const key in obj) 
  total += obj[key].length;
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const obj = {
  one: [1, 4],
  two: [4, 6]
}

let total = 0;

Object.keys(obj).forEach(element => { total += obj[element].length  } )

console.log(total);
```

Comment: Your answer does not run: `Uncaught ReferenceError: sum is not defined`

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks, now is correct

Comment: It would probably be simpler (and more efficient) to use `Object.values` than to get the keys and then access each associated value through the object.

Comment: Yes, I know but the best option is using flat() like above in answer.
I wrote my answer very fast and I don't had a time to thinking. Peace!

Answer (score 1):

[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on [`Object.values(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) would be a great fit:

```js
const obj = {
  one: [1, 4],
  two: [4, 6]
}

let total = Object.values(obj).reduce((prev, cur) => prev + cur.length, 0);

console.log(total); // 4
```